# Why does exec {fd}<file assign file descriptor of file to fd?

Tags: bash

I found a code which gets a file descriptor of 'file'. The code is following.

```
exec {fd}<'file'
```

Unfortunately, the code did not provide why it can get a file descriptor by exec. Even after I read the manual of bash, I could not understand what command the exec executes here. Someone who knows the mechanism of the code above, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little weird.

Normally when you run a program, you can specify redirections:

```
cat 0<file #= cat <file
```

This basically creates a process for `cat` by `fork`ing. It then `opens`  `file`,  `dup`s its filedescriptor onto filedescriptor 0, and then `exec`s `cat` within the child.

```
 //Equivalent C code:
 pid=fork();  
 //... (=error checking)
 if(0==pid){
      //child
      int fd; 
      fd = open("file", O_RDONLY);
      //...
      dup2(fd, 0);
      //..
      execvpl("cat", "cat", (char*)0); 
      //..
 }
```

If you instead were to `exec cat 0<file`, there would be no `fork`ing, 
and the redirections and the `exec` call would happen within the current process:

```
int fd; 
fd = open("file", O_RDONLY);
//...
dup2(fd, 0);
//..
execvpl("cat", "cat", (char*)0); 
//..
```

Shells overload `exec` so that if no program to `exec` is provided, only the `open`ing and the `dup`ing  (which together translate to shell redirections) is done within the current process.

That allows you to redirect for the current process:

```
exec 0<file       #standard input is the file "file" from this point forward
```

Bash and other advanced shells further extend this to allow you to use the `exec` syntax to simply open a file and get the file descriptor number.

```
exec {fd}<file
```

is basically their way of doing:

```
fd = open("file", O_RDONLY);
```

Comment: Thank you for beautiful detailed answer. I could understand the mechanism finally. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad it's clear. I had messed up a couple of details in it originally. Hopefully, it should be mostly correct now.

Answer (score 4):

The special bit of syntax is the braces around the identifier. Normally, you specify an expression that evalutes to an integer value like

```
exec 3<file   # Open file for reading on fd 3
fd=5
exec $fd<file # Open file for reading on fd 5
```

The braces enclose a *name*, not an integer, which asks the shell to find an available descriptor for us, open the file on that descriptor, then set the name equal to that value.

```
# Pretend there is a function called get_avail_fd
# Then the following is something like
#     fd=$(get_available_descriptor)
#     exec $fd<file
# except there is no race condition or need to lock
# file descriptor between the call to get_avail_fd and exec
exec {fd}<file
```

Comment: thank you for providing a practical knowledge and usage.